# Rails 3 - Oberserver - Not able to user the Devise @current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Im building a Rails 3 app, and have an Observer...

in the observer I need to user the current_user var that DEVISE allows me to user across my views...

How can you use the current_user.name or current_user.id in the Observer?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create **User.current** accessor, which sets/reads **Thread.current[:user]**:

http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/47-fetch-current-user-in-models